# Is there a way to post/send a large picture/photo/image to user's friend?

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-opengraph

My canvas app has to send kisses to user's friends. The conditions are:

- the picture has to be large, not the square format of open graph posts
- the user has to be notified in some way
- link to app canvas must be specified, so that other users can send some kisses

the best solution a found till now is uploading a picture to user's friend(so that the picture can be seen in large format) and write the url to app canvas in the title of the photo. the user is notified that someone posted on his timeline.

on this profile you have some examples: http://www.facebook.com/tiberius.maximus.37

i know that

- open graph actions allow posting large pictures, but only if they are camera pics made by the user.
- simple timeline posts with link or image atached does not comply with the large picture requirement

so, are there any solutions for my problem?

Comment: You’d have to make posts on your wall public for us to see them. And what problem still needs a solution now – sounds to me like you’ve already got what you wanted to achieve?

Comment: i don't like that a photo is uploaded in user's friends photo albums and that i cannot click on the image and go to the app or put a link near like and share that says something like 'send a kiss' ( i saw this on severals other apps but i think it's an open graph thing)

Comment: With normal posts and Open Graph actions, you can supply your own “action links” – but for photos this is not available. You can only put a URL into the message part – it will be rendered as a clickable link, but you can not give it your own link text.